# Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm using mysql phpmyadmin, version 10.1.34-maraiDB.
i cant execute the folling cte code.
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1o1p.png)
[error shown when i run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2xQn.png)

```
WITH cte (Employee_ID, First_Name, Last_Name,Email, Phone, Hire_Date, 
    Manager_ID, Job_Title) AS
(
    SELECT Employee_ID, First_Name, Last_Name,Email, Phone, Hire_Date, 
        Manager_ID, Job_Title
    FROM employees
)

SELECT * FROM cteEmp;
```

Comment: why are you using CTE it is a simple query. and What is CteEmp? You have not specified anywhere

Answer (score 1):

The `WITH` common table expression clause is only supported starting with MariaDB version `10.2.1`.  From the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/):

> Common Table Expression WITH was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.1.

But, you may simply inline your CTE directly into the query, and it should work.  In your particular case, you may just execute the code inside the CTE:

```
SELECT Employee_ID, First_Name, Last_Name,Email, Phone, Hire_Date,
    Manager_ID, Job_Title
FROM employees;
```

Comment: we were required to use a recursive SQL join inside a CTE which I couldn't figure out if my code was right or wrong since it was not working on my version. maybe i`ll try updating my MaraiDB version.

Comment: @jeromenas Check the MariaDB documentation, because recursive CTE requires an even higher version than what I listed above for non recursive CTE.

Comment: currently downloading

Comment: Recursive Common Table Expressions have been supported since MariaDB 10.2.2.