# Cannot use with in query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following query:

```
with current_round as (
select * 
from match_case_1
where round_id = 12696
)
select *
from current_round cr
where
(
    not exists(select * from current_round where gameweek is null)
)
or 
(
    exists(select * from current_round where status = 1) 
    and not exists(select * from current_round where gameweek is not null)
    and cr.status = 1    
)
or 
(
    not exists(select * from current_round where status = 1)
    and not exists(select * from current_round where gameweek is not null)
    and cast(cr.`datetime` as date) = (
        select max(cast(`datetime` as date)) as `date`
        from current_round
        where status = 5 or status = 3
    )
);
```

Which essentially apply specific condition, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247116/how-to-execute-different-query-based-on-returned-value) for more details, the problem's that PhpMyAdmin seems not able to recognize `with` operator, infact I get:

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "with" at position 0)

What can I do?

Comment: This may be solve your problem [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759466/unrecognized-statement-type-near-with-at-position-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759466/unrecognized-statement-type-near-with-at-position-0)

Comment: @SurajSingh it say page not found

Comment: @SurajSingh, it's working in fiddle cause you select mysql version 8 but it is not avialble in lower version

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . Upgrade to MySQL 8+ if you want to use CTEs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated right now to the latest version of MSQL, I get: `Error processing request
Error code: 500
Error message: Internal Server Error` this error is returned by PhpMyAdmin when I paste the query above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select * 
    from match_case_1
    where round_id = 12696 and not exists(select * from match_case_1 where gameweek is null)
```

Comment: Should `current_round` be `match_case_1` or alias?

Comment: @sfarzoso, it will be match_case_1 , I've updated it - you can check now

Comment: I see thanks, but if you look at the link in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247116/how-to-execute-different-query-based-on-returned-value full query have an access to `current_round` table which is a temp table, should I use an alias near `match_case_1`? I also updated the question

Answer (score 1):

That's because there is no `with` operator in mysql.

> What can I do?

Use valid syntax